# NodeJS on production server - permissions

Tags: linux, node.js, git, ubuntu

I want to have `node` and `npm` available for whatever user is on the system.

In our team, when someone updates code from git they run:`sudo -u www-data git pull`

So whatever project it is, we always go through `www-data` user.

Now we have new Node project and need to do the same. There is no way that on our production server we will rely on one user handling everything about node - what if he leaves tomorrow?

So we are not using NVM, but installing Node as a root as [described here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

Its all fine, and all users see `node` and `npm` executable. Problems start when we actually try to use them.

What you want to do is:

```
cd /var/www/node_project
sudo -u www-data git pull
sudo -u www-data npm install
```

This fails on last command, because `npm` is trying to write `lock` file in my home directory. So:`/home/user/.npm` instead of somewhere globally or `/var/www/.npm` which would be home directory for www-data user.

Similar to that, after installing

`sudo npm install -g typings`

And then running `sudo -u www-data typings install` you get an error, because it is trying to write `/home/user/.config/configstore/insight-typings.json`

Could someone please elaborate how to actually properly install node on server? If I run `sudo -u www-data` how come npm ins still going into my home folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify directory for global installs from some user:

set `prefix = ~/.where_to_install` in `~/.npmrc`

then add in PATH variable proper location for executables (like `~/.npm/bin`)

Btw, what is home dir for www-data in your case?

Comment: but I dont want global packages to be installed per-user base. I want them to be installed for everyone, which is working at the moment, the only issue is that global packages are still trying to write something  into users local directory AND the wrong user. If I run command as user user1 `sudo -u www-data tsc` tsc should write whatever it needs into www-data home directory rather than user1 home directory. www-data home directory is `/var/www`

Comment: hmm, `user` user has same id as www-data?

Comment: How can two users have the same id? They are two differenet os users

Comment: Actually, in UNIX-like they can. It's very strange, why `sudo oneuser` want do something from `anotheruser`...

Comment: I checked, just to be sure. `www-data` has id 33 `user1` has id 1003

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Yet I think maybe you have some specific settings for sudoers or user id's issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104845/discussion-between-tom-and-loadaverage).

Comment: Accepting this answer based on discussion, follow link above